# Как пишется «не поддающийся»?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

«Абсолютно не поддающаяся дрессировке собака». Склоняюсь к тому, что пишется раздельно. Есть зависимое слово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Абсолютно не поддающаяся дрессировке собака.**

Раздельно, но не потому, что есть зависимое слово, а потому, что есть пояснительное слово *"дрессировке"*.

> При наречии меры или степени в качестве зависимого слова *"не"* с
> причастиями пишется слитно... Но если, помимо таких наречий, при
> причастии имеются еще другие пояснительные слова, то по общему правилу
> *"не"* с причастием пишется раздельно: *совершенно не подготовленная к
> набору рукопись*; *совсем не решённая до сих пор проблема*
> ([Розенталь "Орфография", § 60.3](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80)).